# ¿Como instalar ubuntu en una HP modelo RTL8723BE? Problemas durante la instalación

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Actualmente tengo windows 10, instalado por defecto. Pero, necesito instalar ubuntu por trabajo. Estuve intentando instalarlo. Ya realicé los pasos comunes que recomienda la página de ubuntu https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#3-usb-selection

Pero, no sirvió. Intenté con dos versiones de ubuntu la 20.4 LTS (actual) y la 18.4.1 LTS. Pero ninguna resultó suele detenerse al momento.

Suele quedarse cargando en este punto. Ya sea con o sin internet.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Probaste sin la opción de descargar actualizaciones? Es posible que haya algún lío con el controlador de la tarjeta de red o la de wifi. Así mismo, sugiero marques la opción de instalar programas de terceros, pues es posible que el chipset o alguna tarjeta requiera controladores no-open-source.

Comment: ¿Estás instalándolo individualmente (solo UBUNTU formateando el disco entero) o en modo dual (UBUNTU junto a tu WINDOWS ya instalado)?

Comment: si, probé sin esa opción, y la opción sin internet

Comment: ni siquiera alcanza a llegar a ese punto, no avanza después del formulario de la imagen

Comment: ¿El botón de **continuar** te deja presionarlo? ¿O ni siquiera podés tocar algún botón en esa parte de la imagén?

Comment: se queda presionado, y el puntero queda con la imagen de cargando

Comment: Después de eso creo que sigue la definición del particionamiento en disco y eso no tiene mayor lío. Yo comprobaría que el ISO está correctamente descargado y que la imagen que arrancaste está correctamente creada. Usa la signature de la imagen para validarla y usa unetbootin si usas USB

Comment: seguí los pasos recomendados en la página de ubuntu usando RUFUS para volver mi usb booteable, y descargué varias veces las versiones, y diferentes. Por si era ese el problema.

Comment: Es un bug medio raro. Para mí es un problema con la distribución. Alguien que me corrobore.
Te sugeriría que instales otra distribución que es similar que puede que te funcione. Pero no quiero que se te haga muy complejo.

Comment: Gracias, podrías explicarme lo de la distribución? Te refieres a algo del disco duro?

Comment: No. Con distribución me refiero a otra **"versión"** de Linux, por decirlo de algún modo. Cada uno tiene características y diferencias, pero cada 1 es el mismo sistema operativo, Linux. Hay muchas y en este caso te recomendaría(si tu Sistema tiene limitaciones de hardware) Linux Lite: https://www.linuxliteos.com/download.php

Y si necesitás una distribución con una interfaz bonita y amigable del lado del usuario te recomiendo LinuxMint: https://www.linuxmint.com/

Comment: Es una HP corei 5 de 7ma generación, con ram de 8GB y vi los requisitos mínimos para el sistema. Mi computadora tiene la capacidad.

Comment: ¡Excelente!
Te recomendaría entonces **LinuxMint** con la versión del escritorio ***Cinnamon*** que es la más intuitiva. Suerte y espero que no te ocurra el bug ocurrido con Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

revisa en las Bios que no tengas activa alguna configuración que bloquee la instalación de software desconocidos, trata antes de instalar ubuntu desde el mismo windows dimensionar las particiones de los discos para que tengas una partición exclusiva para el ubuntu.